# Index Post not returning entire model to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return entire model data to index post when form submit. It is returning ID only which passed in URL parameter. Why?

[image]

```
@using Volunteer.BootstrapSupport
@model IEnumerable<Volunteer.Models.Activity>
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h2>Member Volunteering List </h2>
    <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >New Activity</button>
    </div>
    <table id="volunteerlist" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover .table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Committee.Name)
                </th>

                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Committee.Type)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Source)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied your View here correctly? Your Model is an IEnumerable and yet there is no indication that you loop on it somewhere. The view you presented here is not valid, that is `model.` won't give any property of `Activity` as it (model) is a collection of  `Activity`.

Comment: I don't see inputs elements that would hold your values here, you are only generating labels with DisplayNameFor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Display's for the properties, you need to include hidden fields as well.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Role)
```

Do this for each property that you are not creating an input element for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the model properties to the index you have to add the properties as route values.

return RedirectToAction("Search", new{"key", value});

Hidden fields are one way to store data to pass with a submit, using routing is more complex but better solution as Role url.  For a couple values hidden will work fine but if you find yourself having to create a lot of action links with tons of route values then look into Routing.